# Getting Avalon Wizard to run in VS 2015

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2015, wizard

Looking at trying to use Avalon Wizard in a new project (using VS 2015) and when I try to run the sample I get an error that states:

> "The type 'WizardMvvmBehavior' from assembly 'AvalonWizard.Mvvm' is
>   built with an older version of the Blend SDK, and is not supported in
>   a Windows Presentation Framework 4 project"

The project that I was hoping to use the wizard in is .NET 4.5.2 so I took the source from here and set up the necessary project structure and recompiled.

It all recompiles with minor changes and I get a set of assemblies which I then add to my project. The code *looks* fine (it gets a green check from R#) but when I run it I receive the error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in
>   PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: 'Add value to collection of type
>   'System.Windows.Interactivity.BehaviorCollection' threw an exception.'
>   Line number '38' and line position '21'.

The offending lines are:

```
<aw:Wizard WizardStyle="{Binding SelectedStyle}">
   <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <aw:WizardMvvmBehavior
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Pages}"
                    Controller="{Binding WizardController}" />
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</aw:Wizard>
```

(It breaks on the Controller= line)

What I've tried:

- Recompiling to v4.5.2
- Going through the references and making sure
  that they were set to 4.5 versions where I could
- Changed the build to AnyCPU from x86

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31580864/avalon-wizard-resource-not-found-during-debugging-in-visual-studio-2015) may be related to it but it's received no answers at all.

Comment: If you want to use Behaviors, you need to reference System.Windows.Interactivity.dll. You can find it in c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\.NETFramework\v4.0\Libraries\ or in c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\.NETFramework\v4.5\Libraries\. So try to reference the right version you need from one of these directories.

Comment: @user2250152 Went through the recompiled version with a fine-tooth comb and rechecked all the references (both external and cross-project) Still no cigar and still the same error when I go to run it. Thanks for your help and suggestions!